# Can you use firebase authenticated users as part of Google Cloud IAM Access?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I am developing an application which uses Firebase Authentication for User Authentication.

As part of the solution, I am also using Google Cloud Run to run some web engines. I know that I can restrict access to a given Cloud run instance via Google IAM user accounts/roles.

My question is, can I configure access to a given Cloud Run instance to specific firebase users? Could I dynamically create  a group and then assign a subset of firebase users to this group which would then have access to the clound run service?

If so, is there anything you can provide in regards to how I would do this?

Thx

Comment: You mean you want to grant the access to Cloud Run only to a subset of your Firebase user? If so, it's not possible, Firebase, like IAM, perform only authentication and not authorization (at the end, only authorization for accessing to Google Services). If you grant access to Cloud Run only on authenticated users, without distinctions, I have a solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no configuration for this in Cloud Run.  If you need to control access to Firebase Auth users (on any backend, not just Cloud Run), then you'll need to pass along an ID token to the backend, and [verify it with the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).  Your code will then need to decide what to do with that user's request.

Comment: Thx for the response. If I was using Google Identity service for authentication, would this integrate via IAM to Cloud run? I can see you can restrict  access to Cloud run via AIM usrs/roles.

Comment: I'm not sure.  That sounds like maybe a different and more specific question to ask separately?

Comment: @mikehennessy IAM authentication for Cloud Run is for Service<=>Service network; it's not for authenticating end-users in their browser.